# PhoneGap / Android accelerometer showing strange values

Tags: android, cordova, accelerometer, phonegap-build

I used information and code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761509/1469208) (rewriting code to Javascript) in my simple demo PhoneGap Buld application, to recalculate gravity (`G`) to real acceleration (`m/s2`) with 1 second frequency.

This is actual code (important part):

```
function onAccelerationSuccess(acceleration)
{
    var g = 9.80665;

    acceleration.x = (acceleration.x * g).toFixed(2) + ' m/s\u00b2';
    acceleration.y = (acceleration.y * g).toFixed(2) + ' m/s\u00b2';
    acceleration.z = ((acceleration.z + 1) * g).toFixed(2) + ' m/s\u00b2';
    ...
}

watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onAccelerationSuccess, onAccelerationError, {frequency: 1000});
```

Mentioned answer and many, many sources claims, that with my phone lying on the table face-up, I should get values of `(0, 0, -1)` G for the `x`, `y`, and `z` axes respectively. Assuming Earth's natural acceleration (`g = 9.80665`), I should see real acceleration values of `(0, 0, 9.81)` m/s2 and these values should not change (as phone is resting still). Am I right?

However, actually I'm seeing, that my real values are:

- X axis: `-1.87`, `-1.50`, `-2.25`,
- Y axis: `2.26`, `1.88`, `1.51`, `0.76`,
- Z axis: `101.87`, `101.49`, `102.25`, `102.62`, `103.37`.

These values are constantly changing, but only between these mentioned, and not every axis gets changed value each second. Sometimes, a value for some axis remains for 2-3 seconds.

What is happening? How can a phone variate its acceleration, if it is holding still on my desk? How can any device, that is not moving in any direction have such enormous acceleration like 100 m/s2?

I have heard that accelerators on-board mobile devices are more like toy than real  a measurement device and that they're producing a lot of noise or jitter to returned values. But, for God sake, this is a complete garbage, that is making use of this function completely pointless.

I tested this code on Google Nexus (first edition) phone, with Android 4.2.2. App with Phonegap 2.9.0.

**EDIT**: I've tested my mobile application with Ripple Emulator and I'm getting perfectly valid values:

```
Acceleration in the X axis is 0.00 m/s².
Acceleration in the Y axis is 0.00 m/s².
Acceleration in the Z axis is 9.81 m/s².
```

Is something wrong with accelerometer / compass / gyro on-board my Nexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bug. I've read many SO questions about iOS native programming in ObjectiveC, when I was dealing with accelerometer. And I missed [PhoneGap API documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Acceleration), which says, that values passed are already recalculated:

> Acceleration values include the effect of gravity (9.81 m/s^2).

After removing double gravity calculation all seems to be fine.

I'm betting values +/-`0.3` m/s2 for `x` and `y` axis and around `10.3`-`10.4` m/s2 for `z` axis, when phone is lying on my desk. But I assume, these are variations and mentioned noise, that is comming from fairly cheap accelerometer chip used in mobile devices.